# What takes up the most space in the database

Tags: database

I'm Building a website that also contains a forum. The part I'm missing to build is the "post view counter", but I'm not sure what way I should go.

I've 2 ways I was thinking about using in my head, but what would be best and would there be a difference in the Space each option use in the `database`

Method 1:

```
PostId | UserId's (separated by, and max 200 users per row)
-----------------------------------
   1   | 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 220
   2   | 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 220
```

Method 2:

```
PostId | UserId
-----------------------------------
   1   | 1
   1   | 2
   1   | 4
   1   | 5
   1   | 9
   1   | 10
   1   | 220
```

Do these 2 methods take equal size in the database? or would there be an option that would be way better to store the data about WHO has viewed what post?

Comment: Method 1 would be a database which needs to be normalized. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
So method 2 is a good way, method 1 is a bad way.

Comment: Method 2 makes a lot more sense than method 1

Comment: You use a relational database when you want its features: insert, update, search, sort, enforce referential integrity, handle multi-user environments... Using it as dumb storage of raw bytes is a kind of waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2 is better, specially if you want to keep a "read" status for each user, which in that case I would suggest using `postId` and `userId` as primary key for that table, so you will only hold a single `postId` to `userId` row.
The primary key will place an index in the table, so if you will want to perform a `SELECT` to find out if a user already read that post, it will be very quick.

Note that this will not allow you to count the number of views of the post, and for that I would just place a `viewCount` field on the post itself, and every view of the post will increment this value, regardless if the user already viewed it in the past.